# what could cause vue 2 app to break only on iphone all browsers?

Tags: iphone, vuejs2

I am going crazy at this point I can not figure out this problem. I currently have a vue 2 js application with the following versions:

vue 2.6.10
vue-router 3.0.3
vuex 3.0.1

iphone 11 with IOS 16.6.1

I haven't been able to figure out what is causing this behavior, when I access my web app it reloads multiple times and then I get a blank page that says A problem repeatedly occurred on "URL" Sometimes I am able to load the page but as soon as I start scrolling and get more data (infinite scroll) it reloads and then see the same message.

I connected the iphone to a mac computer to checkout the inspector tool but I dont get any error messages.

Do you guys have any suggestions?